Downloader with python
I took this piece of code from a youtube video as I pasted it and the IDE gives me an error:
from pytube import YouTube

url = "https://youtu.be/GNWPFG-Swks"

mi_video = YouTube(url)

mi_video1 = mi_video.streams.get_highest_resolution()

mi_video1.download()

I downloaded the necessary Pytube and Moviepy libraries. I tried other methods and nothing, In the videos it does work but it doesn't for me
This is IDE error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Portfolio\Building A Video Downloader App\prueba.py", line 7, in <module>
    mivideo = mivideo.streams.get_highest_resolution()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 176, in fmt_streams       
    stream_manifest = extract.apply_descrambler(self.streaming_data)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 160, in streaming_data    
    self.bypass_age_gate()
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 257, in bypass_age_gate   
    innertube_response = innertube.player(self.video_id)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\innertube.py", line 448, in player
    return self._call_api(endpoint, query, self.base_data)        
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\innertube.py", line 390, in _call_api        
    response = request._execute_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 37, in _execute_request    
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 215, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 521, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 630, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 559, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 492, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\JONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 639, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

I'm learning Python and I want to know where I'm going wrong.

This question is similar to: How to solve HTTP Error 400: Bad Request in PyTube?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Here is your updated script with the client version modification:
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube.innertube import _default_clients

_default_clients["ANDROID"]["context"]["client"]["clientVersion"] = 
"19.08.35"
_default_clients["IOS"]["context"]["client"]["clientVersion"] = "19.08.35"
_default_clients["ANDROID_EMBED"]["context"]["client"]["clientVersion"] = 
"19.08.35"
_default_clients["IOS_EMBED"]["context"]["client"]["clientVersion"] = 
"19.08.35"
_default_clients["IOS_MUSIC"]["context"]["client"]["clientVersion"] = "6.41"
_default_clients["ANDROID_MUSIC"] = _default_clients["ANDROID_CREATOR"]

url = "https://youtu.be/GNWPFG-Swks"
mi_video = YouTube(url)
mi_video1 = mi_video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
mi_video1.download()


I already did it and the mistakes continue. This time the execution takes a while and then it shows the mistakes

did u copy my code 'cause i think it might work in that way.

Ensure you have the latest version of pytube installed. You can update it using the following command:

pip install --upgrade pytube

please answer me


Ensure you have the latest version of PyTube, as updates often include fixes for these issues.
pip install --upgrade pytube

Locate the cipher.py file in your PyTube installation directory. This is typically found in Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py.
Open the file in a text editor and find the line that looks like this:
var {nfunc}\s*=\s*([.+?];)
Change it to:
var {nfunc}\s*=\s*([.+?])

Save the modified (cipher.py) file:
Restart your Python environment or IDE to ensure the changes take effect.


